# Keeping a single bibliography up to date in Overleaf

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, overleaf

Say I have many similar projects running at the same time. I want to use the same bibliography for each project, so far I have just been updating one and copying it into the other projects. However this is laborious and sometimes I forget to do it, is there a streamlined way in which I only need to keep a single bibliography up to date, which can then be called in every project?

Comment: In a local environment using '\include` would be a way to do it. // Should also work with remote files, e.g. including from a cloud server.

Comment: You should probably tag this with overleaf as well (then their support people can easily find it). I'm not sure separate projects on overleaf can see each others files.

Comment: see https://de.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Can_I_share_files_(e.g._.bib_and_some_graphics)_across_my_projects%3F

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks!